# free() not working even after I used malloc() to allocate memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

`free()` does not seem to de-allocate memory when I compile. I have previously allocated using `malloc()` and I tested it to ensure the pointer is not null.

These are the **errors** I get when I compile my code:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee53e1aa4: pointer being freed was
>   not allocated malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to
>   debug

```
void math(int array[], int length, int* sum, int* mult);

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int mult = 1 ;
    int a[] = {1, 33, 12, 2, 9, 2};

    int* sump = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));

    if(sump == NULL){
        printf("sump is null");
    }

    int* multp = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));

    if(multp == NULL){
        printf("multp is null");
    }

    sump = &sum;
    multp = &mult;

    math(a, 6, sump, multp);

   if(sump != NULL){
       free(sump);
   }
if(multp != NULL){
       free(multp);
   }

    printf("sum: %d mult: %d\n", sum, mult);


    return 0;
}

void math(int array[], int length, int* sump, int* multp)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 1; 
    int mult = 1;

    for(i=0; i<length;++i){
        sum += array[i];
        mult *= array[i];

    }

    printf("%d %d\n", sum, mult);

    *multp = mult;
    *sump = sum;   

}
```

Comment: You should actually abort the program in the case of the `NULL` tests being true

Comment: `sump = &sum;` losses the allocated value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `sump = &sum;` means that the pointer `sump` now points at the automatic variable `sum`,  so you get an error when you try to free it. `free(sump);` means to free the memory which `sump` is pointing to.

Comment: You're trying to free `&sum` and `&mult`, not the addresses malloc returned. Malloc didn't return `&sum` so freeing `&sum` is not allowed.

Comment: The code should be `*sump = sum;` | `*multp = mult;` .

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I lost an edit, it's fixed now. I'll delete this comment later.

Comment: That's a run-time error, not a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* sump = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

`sump` now points to an anonymous object created by `malloc`.

```
sump = &sum;
```

Now `sump` points to the object `sum` that you defined earlier. The allocated object is lost.

```
if(sump != NULL){
    free(sump);
}
```

The `NULL` check is unnecessary, since `free(NULL)` is legal and does nothing. But since `sump` no longer points to an allocated object, `free(sump)` has undefined behavior. (You're lucky that your run-time system was able to diagnose it for you.)

The error message was generated at run time, not at compile time.

And you're missing the required `#include` directives at the top of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: @brhans. No, that's not true.

Comment: nvm - I was seeing double.